# How to record the trajectory of vertex world coordinate in OpenInventor?

Tags: openinventor

I am a freshman in the use of Open Inventor.

There is a cube whose center point is not the origin point. the cube itself rotates , while it revolves around the origin point.I need to record the path of one vertex of the cube during rotating and resolving.Could you please give me some clues?

Thanks in advance.

I just only draw points by OpenIventor.

Answer (score 0):

The cube rotates and revolves according to some transform applied to the cube geometry.  At any given time step, the position of the "one vertex" of the cube is the cube transform applied to the original vertex.

If the cube transform is an accumulation of rotations applied during traversal of the scene graph, then, in Open Inventor, you can get the complete transform using the SoGetMatrixAction class. Something like:

```
OnTimeStep()
{
  // Get the current cube transform
  SoPath* pathToCube = . . .
  SoGetMatrixAction gma;
  gma.apply( pathToCube );
  SbMatrix mat = gma.getMatrix();

  // Compute the new vertex position
  SbVec3f theVertex = . . .
  SbVec3f newVertex;
  mat.multVecMatrix( theVertex, newVertex );
  // Record the new vertex position
}
```